# disable the UIview elements from another view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, user-interaction

I am trying to disable the user interaction to the view from one view. Below is my code.

**DashboardViewControler.m**

```
  if([selectedTitle isEqual:@"VIEW"])
  {
     LatLongViewController * latview =[[LatLongViewController alloc]init];
     latview.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;  
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController" sender:self];
  }
```

In the `latview`, I have `UITextField` and `UILabel`. I want to disable the user interaction while above scenario matches. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you disable the text fields, so the user can#t access them after being disabled. Otherwise, you can set latView on hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
latview.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

You can't do it with `IBOutlet`. All `IBOutlet` are
operated by `ViewController`. Here is my solution:

-Create new `BOOL` in **LatLongViewController.h** file:

```
@property BOOL editMode;
```

-In **DashboardViewControler.m**

```
  if([selectedTitle isEqual:@"VIEW"])
  {
     LatLongViewController * latview =[[LatLongViewController alloc]init];
     latview.editMode = NO;
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController" sender:self];
  }
```

-In **LatLongViewController.m**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
       if(_editMode == NO){
          view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
       }
    }
```

I think you should use `textfield.enable = NO;` if u have only one `UITextField` in this view.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `UIViewController` owns the concerned views as properties:

```
yourTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

A beginners guide how to connect an view `IBOutlet` from `Storyboard` can  be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html).

To disable user interaction for all subviews, iterate over them:

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
    view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to disable all the elements in the UIview ?

Comment: Updated answer acordingly